# Bash comparison and expression operators

Tags: command-line, bash, programming, scripts

I'm new to bash programming. I've read two good, long guides, but they made a mess in my head about operators and keywords.

Which are more commonly and widely used? I don't know when to use which and why.

1. `test`, `[[ ]]` or `[ ]` or even `(( ))`
2. `$((exp))` or `$[exp]`
3. `-gt` or `>`, `ge` or `>=` etc.
4. when to use `<` and `>` or `( )` and when we have to escape it with `\:` `\<`  `\(` etc.
5. `==` or `=` (string comparisons)

I know the basic differences between `[` and `[[` but other questions are a mystery for me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: A very useful wiki that is up to date and mentions much good practice is [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/). The Bash guide and the FAQ on there are particularly useful.

Answer (score 5):

- `test` is a shell built-in which (obviously) tests for some given condition. Some older shells need a special command. So you'll find also a program at `/usr/bin/test`.
- `[` is also a program to test for some condition. This software needs also a closing bracket and you can find it at `/usr/bin/[`.
- `[[…]]` is an alternative to `test` and `[`. It was developed for the Korn shell (`ksh`). But you also find it in Bash versions greater than 2 and in the Z Shell. The double brackets have some nifty features:

  - The shell does no word splitting or file name expansion.
  - You need no quoting.
  - Instead of `-a` (AND) or `-o` (OR) you can use `&&` or `||`.
  - The `=` can do a lot more.
- `((…))` is equivalent to `let`. So basically `((expression))` is the same as `let "expression"`. However with `let` you can use more than one expression, but double braces only allow one expression.
- `$((…))` (and also `$[…]`) does some calculation. You shell tries to calculate the expression inside the braces and replaces the expression with the result. So `echo $((1+1))` leads to `echo 2`. So your shells prints the number 2.

Every time when you want to compare two numbers you should use the option with a dash and two letters (`-ge`, `-lt` etc.). If you want to compare strings you should use `=` or `!=`.

Your question regarding escaping is quite hard to answer. Because it depends on the software you use besides from the shell. So i.e. `grep` and `grep -E` need different escaping. This is also the case with `sed`, `awk` and others. So the best option is to have a look at the manpage. After some time you get accustomed and know when to use escaping.

Comment: thank you. one more question - because its possible to do comparison using ((...)) - is it more common to use this version: if (( 2 > 1 )) OR this: if [[ 2 -gt 1 ]]

Comment: I would assume that `if [ 2 -gt 1 ]; …` is more common, because I see this more often in shell scripts and as far as I know this is POSIX compliant.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that [ expression ] is true if expression evaluates to/returns zero, but (( expression )) is true if expression evaluates to/returns non-zero.